# Get symbols before space and after (JS)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have angular component where I have phone number

for example `+36 42534534534`

I need to get code before space and phone number before space.

I make it like this

```
set phoneNumberResult(value: string) {
    if (this.phoneNumberResult !== value) {
        this.phoneCode = value.substr(0, 3);
        this.phoneNumber = value.substr(5, value.length - 5);
        this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
    }
}
```

But phone code can be 3 or 4 or 5 symbols.
So I need to get all symbols before space and all after space to get `phoneCode` and `phoneNumber`

How I can do this correctly?

Comment: what if you just split it by the empty space? `var [prefix, phoneno] = '+36 42534534534.split(' ');` where `prefix` will become +36 and `phoneno` will become 42534534534

Comment: use split: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: if it´s a string you can use Split() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_split.htm

Answer (score 2):

Try [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with space.

```js
let value = `+36 42534534534`
let valueSplit = value.split(' ');
let phoneCode = valueSplit[0]
let phoneNumber = valueSplit[1]

console.log(phoneCode)
console.log(phoneNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `split` ([read more about split here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) if the string input format is always the same, meaning it always has the prefix separated by the number with an empty space.

```
set phoneNumberResult(value: string) {
    if (this.phoneNumberResult !== value) {
        let [phoneCode, phoneNumber] = value.split(' ');
        this.phoneCode = phoneCode;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
    }
}
```

`split`, in your case, will return an array where the first element will be the left side of the splitted string and the second element will be the right side of it.

Sample fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/mcxuorhf/